# What's mean of template<typename T, T*> in c++ templates?

Tags: c++, templates

What's mean of `template<typename T, T*>` in c++ templates?
And in what situation，i should use it？

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T, T*> 
void test(T a)
{
    cout << "test template\n";
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    test(10);
    return 0;
}
```

I got a compile error from above code.

```
./test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
./test.cpp:12: error: no matching function for call to ‘test(int)’
```

change `test(10);` to `test<int, int*>(10);`, still don't work.

Comment: It's called a [*non-type  template parameter*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Non-type_template_parameter)

Comment: @NathanOliver      how can i invoke the template function test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usage would be:

```
extern int global;

int main()
{
    test<int, &global>(10);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b2b3e1b097a5a947)